Encountered PUT Error Code 405 (Method Not Allowed) in production on Next.js 14
I want to be able to update the theme.json data via the route.ts PUT method when the website is in production mode, but an error occurs when I try to update the data.
Repository: https://github.com/gdwmw/DIZETO/tree/development
enter image description here
public/database/theme.json
[{"theme":"system"}]

src/app/api/theme/route.ts
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await fs.readFile("./public/database/theme.json", "utf-8");
    return new Response(data);
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Failed to get theme" }), { status: 500 });
  }
};

export const PUT = async (request: Request) => {
  try {
    const theme = await request.json();
    const themeStringify = JSON.stringify([theme]);
    await fs.writeFile("./public/database/theme.json", themeStringify, "utf-8");
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Theme changed successfully" }), { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Failed to change theme" }), { status: 500 });
  }
};

.env
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL="http://localhost:3000/"

src/utils/api/theme/index.tsx
const API_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "/api/theme";

if (!API_URL) {
  throw new Error("The API URL is not defined. Please check your environment variables.");
}

export interface ITheme {
  theme: string;
}

export const GETTheme = async (): Promise<ITheme[]> => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(API_URL, { cache: "no-cache" });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch: Theme with status ${res.status}`);
    }

    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const PUTTheme = async (data: ITheme): Promise<ITheme> => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      method: "PUT",
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to put: Theme with status ${res.status}`);
    }

    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

src/layouts/home/modules/header/index.tsx
import { FC, ReactElement } from "react";

import { dehydrate, HydrationBoundary, QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

import { GETTheme } from "@/utils";

import { Navbar } from "./batches";

export const Header: FC = async (): Promise<ReactElement> => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryFn: GETTheme,
    queryKey: ["GETTheme"],
  });

  return (
    <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
    </HydrationBoundary>
  );
};

src/layouts/home/modules/header/batches/navbar/index.tsx
"use client";

import { FC, ReactElement } from "react";

import { useMutation, useQuery, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { BsList } from "react-icons/bs";

import { useGlobalStates } from "@/hooks/global";
import { ButtonTWM } from "@/interfaces/buttons/button";
import logoDIZETO from "@/public/assets/images/logos/dizeto.svg";
import { GETTheme, PUTTheme } from "@/utils";

import { IconBasedOnTheme } from "./IconBasedOnTheme";

export const LINKS_DATA = [
  { href: "#about", label: "About" },
  { href: "#portfolio", label: "Portfolio" },
  { href: "#pricing", label: "Pricing" },
  { href: "#testimony", label: "Testimony" },
  { href: "#client", label: "Client" },
  { href: "#contact", label: "Contact" },
];

export const Navbar: FC = (): ReactElement => {
  const { data: dataTheme } = useQuery({
    queryFn: GETTheme,
    queryKey: ["GETTheme"],
  });

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { setTheme, theme } = useTheme();
  const { openASide, setOpenASide } = useGlobalStates();

  const handleUpdateTheme = useMutation({
    mutationFn: PUTTheme,
    onSuccess: async () => {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["GETTheme"] });
    },
  });

  const handleTheme = () => {
    if (theme === "dark") {
      setTheme("system");
      handleUpdateTheme.mutate({ theme: "system" });
    } else if (theme === "system") {
      setTheme("light");
      handleUpdateTheme.mutate({ theme: "light" });
    } else {
      setTheme("dark");
      handleUpdateTheme.mutate({ theme: "dark" });
    }
  };

  return (
    <nav className="fixed left-0 top-0 w-full">
      <ul className="flex items-center justify-between px-10 py-3 font-semibold">
        <li className="flex size-[40px] items-center">
          <Link href="#hero">
            <Image alt="DIZETO" priority src={logoDIZETO} width={35} />
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul className="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:gap-5 md:gap-10 lg:gap-16">
            {LINKS_DATA.map((dt, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <Link className={ButtonTWM({ color: "black", size: "sm", variant: "ghost" })} href={dt.href}>
                  {dt.label}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul className="flex gap-2">
            <li className="flex size-[40px] items-center justify-end">
              <button className={ButtonTWM({ color: "black", size: "sm", variant: "ghost" })} onClick={handleTheme} type="button">
                <IconBasedOnTheme dataTheme={dataTheme} />
              </button>
            </li>
            <li className="flex size-[40px] items-center justify-end sm:hidden">
              <button className={ButtonTWM({ color: "black", size: "sm", variant: "ghost" })} onClick={() => setOpenASide(!openASide)} type="button">
                <BsList className="mr-[-4px]" size={30} />
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

src/layouts/home/modules/header/batches/navbar/IconBasedOnTheme.tsx
import { FC, ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import { BsFillMoonFill, BsFillSunFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { SiMoonrepo } from "react-icons/si";

import { ITheme } from "@/utils";

type T = {
  dataTheme: ITheme[] | undefined;
};

export const IconBasedOnTheme: FC<T> = ({ dataTheme }): ReactElement => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState<null | ReactElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (theme) {
      case "system":
        setIcon(<SiMoonrepo size={22} />);
        break;
      case "light":
        setIcon(<BsFillSunFill size={22} />);
        break;
      case "dark":
        setIcon(<BsFillMoonFill size={22} />);
        break;
    }
  }, [theme]);

  const initialIconValue = () => {
    if (dataTheme?.[0].theme === "system") {
      return <SiMoonrepo size={22} />;
    } else if (dataTheme?.[0].theme === "light") {
      return <BsFillSunFill size={22} />;
    } else {
      return <BsFillMoonFill size={22} />;
    }
  };

  return icon ?? initialIconValue();
};

I want to be able to update the theme.json data via the route.ts PUT method when the website is in production mode, but an error occurs when I try to update the data.

Could you please also post the error?

okey done, you can check it

Does this only happen in your prod environment or also on the dev server?

only happen in production

when i run it in dev mode, all functions work fine, but when i build and then i start, error occurs when i change the theme.

I am cloning the repo right now. IIRC this could be a configuration option.

okay, take your time.

You shouldnt be hard-coding your URLs like that. I am running 2 servers and one is on port 3000 so it can't even request the URL. If I run the dev server first, the main server doesn't even start up because of the port conflict.

Ok, can you give me the solution code? First of all I apologize for asking for the correct solution code, because I don't know which one is correct, I'm still in the learning process now.

The issue doesn't lie with the with the actual serverside code, rather that the entire next app is refusing the PUT request. This sounds like a config issue to me. I'll dig a bit deeper

Okay, take your timebtw thank you for helping me.

What's happening as well is that it tries to fetch localhost:3000//api/theme. Your ENV is set up improperly

This is extremely strange to me. When fetching with GET, it just returns the JSON response, but when fetching with PUT it returns an entire HTML page.

This seems like a bug in Next.js, I tried to create a new project then I gave 2 methods to route.ts, namely GET and PUT, what happened was an error, but if I only gave one method, namely PUT, it ran smoothly.

but if I give 2 methods namely PUT and POST on route.ts, it runs smoothly, it seems there is a problem with the GET method.

Yea when I define a POST method on it, it works as well...

Omg this is very strange, LOL

Im gonna test it without the GET method and see if that works

Strangely, it works without the GET method defined. I think at the end of all of this, you should definitely report this to the nextjs developers

Should this be reported to next.js developers? What do you think?

But how to report it, LOL

Go on the nextjs github and open an issue. From my testing, when GET and PUT are the only defined methods, it breaks. I also tried changing the order in which they are defined. Do you have discord so we can move the bug report discussion there?

ok, we discuss via discord, invite me, my username is "landensaki"
